# JQUERY keyup function response only when mouse is not over input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a problem with keyup function

I have a ordering form, wich has x ammount of items, some of them a grouped like:

Item 1 - Group1
Item 2 - Group1

Items who are grouped, have 2 input fields, 1 hidden and 1 visible, what i`m tryng to do, is to change the value of hidden input to the same value of visible input.

My problem is that the value changes only then, when input is no more focused, is there any way to do, that when value changes in focused input, it changes instantly?

Heres how i`m doing it:

```
    $('.item .quantity').on("change paste keyup", function(event) {
        var crr_item = $(this).parents(".item"),
            quantity = $(this).val(),
            items = crr_item.parent().children(".item"),
            group = false;
        if(crr_item.hasClass('group1'))
            group = 'group1';

        else if(crr_item.hasClass('group2'))
            group = 'group2';


        if(crr_item.hasClass('group1_hover'))
            group = 'group1';

        else if(crr_item.hasClass('group2_hover'))
            group = 'group2';

        for(var i = items.index(crr_item)-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var item = items.eq(i);
            if(!item.hasClass(group)) break;
            item.find('.quantity').val(quantity);
            calc_sum_eu(item);
        }
        calc_sum_eu(crr_item);
        for(var i = items.index(crr_item); i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items.eq(i);
            if(!item.hasClass(group)) break;
            item.find('.quantity').val(quantity);
            calc_sum_eu(item);
        }

    });
```

Comment: The `keyup` event should make it update as soon as the user types.

Comment: You can use the new `oninput` event, that should work for every type of input (key, paste).

Comment: Barmar, the thing is, that value changes only then when my mouse is hovered somewhere else, like page backgorund, but if i hover it back to row wich contains focused input, the other input wont change.

Mouser, could you give me more information about this oninput?

Answer (score 1):

try adding a flag on it that will check if it is focused or not

```
var isFocused = false;

$('.item .quantity').on("focus", function(event) {
  isFocused = true;
});

$('.item .quantity').on("blur", function(event) {
  isFocused = false;
});
```

then just add the isFocused variable in your keyup event to validate.